# How to Find the unique rendering ID for a placeholder

Tags: powershell-extensions, presentation, dynamic-placeholder

[image]

We are currently upgrading a site from `8X` to `10.2`. We are trying to change the dynamic placeholders as per `10.2`. But 8.2 dynamic placeholders are of format-

`/a/b_1/c_1`,
`/a/b_1/c_2`,
`/a/b_2/c_3`.

We found that when manually adding rendering to dynamic placeholder in 10.2, the placeholder format is
`/a/b-{UID-a}-0/c-{UID-b}-0`.
How to find the UID of a or b either in Powershell or C# if more than one "a" or "b" is present in Final Rendering XML?
Please refer above snippet of our 8.2 placeholder pattern

Comment: can you please add some screenshots of your presentation how it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Go through utility: https://github.com/rishishekhawat/FixDynamicPlaceholders , i hope it should help you.

[image]

Here you can utilize the code, you can see highlighted area, it is not dependent on old UID, for reference giving code below as well:

```
 foreach (RenderingDefinition rendering in device.Renderings)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rendering.Placeholder))
                    {
                        var newPlaceholder = rendering.Placeholder;
                        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(newPlaceholder, PlaceholderRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                        {
                            var renderingId = match.Value;
                            var newRenderingId = "-{" + renderingId.ToUpper().Substring(1) + "}-0";

                            newPlaceholder = newPlaceholder.Replace(match.Value, newRenderingId);

                            requiresUpdate = true;
                        }

                        result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(rendering.Placeholder, newPlaceholder));
                        rendering.Placeholder = newPlaceholder;
                    }
                }
```

Hope it will help...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in Github codes are converting from pattern /a/b_UID to /a/b-{UID}-0. But my 8X placeholders are in format /a/b_1, /a/b_2

Comment: Currently while this does provide an answer to the question, it is a link only answer. When someone goes on Stack Exchange, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer. Please see this meta post for details on how to update your answer to be Stack Exchange friendly, thanks: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Comment: Updated the  answer with some details...